# CodeIgniter 3 password reset email function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, reset-password

I've made a password reset function for one of my projects.

I'm currently stuck, as I'm not sure how to link my code together.

I've got the email function, reset function and reset link all ready to go. But I'm not sure how to get the reset link to be mailed to the entered email address from the view and the email message to include my reset token and message.

Please have a look at my code and advise if possible, much appreciated.

This is my User controller code

```
public function Email($data){

                $config = array(
                'useragent' => 'codeIgniter',
                'protocol' => 'mail',
                'mailpath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
                'smtp_host' => 'localhost',
                'smtp_user' => 'Myemail',
                'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
                'smtp_port' => 25,
                'smtp_timeout' => 55,
                'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                'wrapchars' => 76,
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'utf-8',
                'validate' => FALSE,
                'priority' => 3,
                'crlf' => "\r\n",
                'newline' => "\r\n",
                'bcc_batch_mode' => FALSE,
                'bcc_batch_size' => 200,
                );

                $this->load->library('email', $config);
                $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
                $this->email->from('myemail');
                $this->email->to('');    //This is where I'm not sure.
                $this->email->subject("Reset Password");
                $this->email->message(); //Next point where I'm not sure
                $this->email->set_mailtype('html');

                if($this->email->send()){
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else{
                    return FALSE;
                }

        }

        public function forgotpassword(){
                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('users/forgotpassword');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

            }
        public function resetlink(){
                $email = $this->input->post('email');
                $result = $this->db->query("select * from users where 
email ='".$email."'")->result_array();
                if(count($result)>0){
                    $token = rand(100000,999999);

                    $this->db->query("update users set password = 
'".$token."' where email = '".$email."'");

                    $message = "Please click on the password reset link 
<br><a href='".base_url('users/reset?token=').$token."'>Reset 
Password</a>";

                    $this->Email($email, 'Reset Password Link', $message);
                }
                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Email not 
 registered');
                    redirect(base_url('users/forgotpassword'));
                }
            }
        public function resetpass(){
            $data['token'] = $this->input->get('token');
            $_SESSION['token'] = $data['token'];
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('users/resetpass');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        public function updatepass(){
            $_SESSION['token'];
            $data = $this->input->post();
            if ($data['password'] == $data ['cpassword']){
                $this->db->query("update users set 
password'".$data['password']."' where password='".$_SESSION['token']."'");
            }
        }
```

This is my forgot password view

```
<style>
                body{
                    background-image: 
url("/assets/images/posts/background12.jpg");
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: cover;
                }
            </style>

            <br>
            <br>
            <form action="<?= base_url('users/resetlink')?>" 
method="post">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        <h2 align="center" >Reset your Password</h2>
                        <br>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" 
name="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <input style="margin-top: 15px" type="submit" 
class="btn btn-info btn-block" value="Send reset link">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 30px" align="center"><?= $this- 
>session->flashdata('message') ?></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Reset Password view

```
<style>
body{
    background-image: url("/assets/images/posts/background12.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<br>
<br>
<form action="<?= base_url('users/resetpass') ?>">
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Reset Password</h1>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <h1 align="center"><?= $this->session->flashdata('message') ?></h1>
            <input type="password" id="email" class="form-control" 
name="password" placeholder="Password" required autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <input type="password" id="email" class="form-control" 
name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required autofocus>
        </div>

        <input style="margin-top: 15px" type="submit" class="btn btn-info 
btn-block" value="Reset password">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

That is all the relevant code I've got for this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you using any authentication library? If so, which one?

Comment: 'form_validation', 'database', 'session'. Those are the libraries i'm using

Comment: If you are not using any auth library, this means you are developing the auth from scratch. I would advise against such approach. An auth library would allow you to implement these features faster and way more securely. IonAuth and CommunityAuth come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your Email function to

```
public function Email($email, $subject, $content){

                $config = array(
                'useragent' => 'codeIgniter',
                'protocol' => 'mail',
                'mailpath' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
                'smtp_host' => 'localhost',
                'smtp_user' => 'Myemail',
                'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
                'smtp_port' => 25,
                'smtp_timeout' => 55,
                'wordwrap' => TRUE,
                'wrapchars' => 76,
                'mailtype' => 'html',
                'charset' => 'utf-8',
                'validate' => FALSE,
                'priority' => 3,
                'crlf' => "\r\n",
                'newline' => "\r\n",
                'bcc_batch_mode' => FALSE,
                'bcc_batch_size' => 200,
                );

                $this->load->library('email', $config);
                $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');
                $this->email->from('myemail');
                $this->email->to($email);    //email address passed into the function.
                $this->email->subject($subject); // subject passed into the function
                $this->email->message($content); //content passed into the function
                $this->email->set_mailtype('html');

                if($this->email->send()){
                    return TRUE;
                }
                else{
                    return FALSE;
                }

        }
```

However, according to the [Codeigniter documentation][1]

[1]: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=complete%20web , you need to send a complete web page.  Therefore you would need something like  -

```
$message = "<html><head><title>Password Reset</title></head><body>Please click on the password reset link <br><a href='".base_url('users/reset?token=').$token."'>Reset Password</a></body></html>";

$this->Email($email, 'Reset Password Link', $message);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback AndyKing.

I managed to get the mail sent with the resetpass link. Now I'm close to the end.

I need to get the update password section working. So how can I use the token that is passed in the url to be the otp for the reset password? 
Because now the only thing that happens is it takes you to the reset password section and when you add new password nothing happens